# Git: how to ignore hidden files / dot files / files with empty file names via .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

These files should all be ignored:

```
.weirdBackupFileType
.travis.yml
```

The following files should not be ignored:

```
_.weirdBackupFileType
Z.travis.yml
```

Comment: I might suggest fixing the title a bit, as "empty file names" doesn't seem to quite fit... Maybe "hidden files" or "dot files" or something... Although, I have to admit, the only reason I looked at this question was to see exactly what an "empty file name" was...

Answer (score 27):

If you want to ignore all dotfiles, add this in your .gitignore file (If it doesn't exist, add it)

```
.*
!.gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is very simple:

This is the content of your `.gitignore` file:

```
# ignore those files 
.weirdBackupFileType
.travis.yml

#DONOT ignore those files (this is what the ! is for - un ignore files)
!_.weirdBackupFileType
!Z.travis.yml
```

And that's it.

In the image you can see that i have created the file and after adding it to the `.gitignore` they are not in the status any more.

[image]