# Gitignore all folders beginning with a period

Tags: git, gitignore, glob

I want to use a `.gitignore` file to ignore all folders beginning with a period (hidden folders of linux).

I can't figure out the syntax, though I'm sure it's simple.

How's it done?

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question as here only dot-folders are wanted, not also dot-files.

Comment: I need to **commit new gitignore file first** to make it take effect

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use one of these patterns:

```
# ignore all . files but include . folders
.*
!.*/
```

---

```
# ignore all . files and . folders
.*

# Dont ignore .gitignore (this file)
# This is just for verbosity, you can leave it out if
# .gitignore is already tracked or if you use -f to
# force-add it if you just created it
!/.gitignore
```

---

```
# ignore all . folders but include . files
.*/
```

---

### ***`What is this pattern?`***

***`.*`***
- This patter tells git to ignore all the files which starts with `.`

***`!`*** - This tells git not to ignore the pattern. In your case `/.gitignore`

A demo can be found in this answer:
[Git: how to ignore hidden files / dot files / files with empty file names via .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543789/git-how-to-ignore-hidden-files-dot-files-files-with-empty-file-names-via-g)

Comment: Including `.gitignore` explicitly is probably descriptive, but unnecessary if .gitignore is already tracked, or added with `-f`. :-) Besides that, it does not answer the question as OP just asked for folders, not files

Comment: You are right, i missed the folders. it should be ** for folders :-)

Comment: No. he wanted **only** folders and your second thing does the same as the first. `.*` will match anything starting with a dot (files *and* folders), `.*/` will match anything starting with a dot that is a folder

Comment: I know, i showed him the patterns, he can grab what he need. i agree

Comment: Well, he can not. As he accepted I guess he didn't mean what he said. But your answer is plainly wrong. `.*` does not ignore all dot-files, but dot-files and dot-folders and `.**` should be the same. Ignoring only the dot-folders would still be `.*/`. :-)

Comment: Ok. feel free to update the answer if in wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

`.*/` will match everything that starts with a dot and is a folder

With the following command you can test it: `mkdir test && cd test && git init && mkdir -p .foo .foo/.bar foo/.bar && touch .foo/dummy .foo/.bar/dummy foo/.bar/dummy && git add . && git status && echo '.*/'>.gitignore && git reset && git add . && git status`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the double asterisk wildcard, which represents directories at any depth.

```
.**/
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.*/` be enough? Should work afair. Update: yes, it is

Comment: It would be if he only wants the first level of directories to be ignored. He said "any" though. This would include directories at directory depth.

Comment: Try the following command and you will see it works fine: `mkdir test && cd test && git init && mkdir -p .foo .foo/.bar foo/.bar && touch .foo/dummy .foo/.bar/dummy foo/.bar/dummy && git add . && git status && echo '.*/'>.gitignore && git reset && git add . && git status`

Comment: Could you give an example? Let's say I have folder named `IgnoreMe` and it appears with the same name in various places and depths in the repository. How could I ignore its content?